# Changing the text format when using the dialogue package

Tags: formatting, align, typography, dialogue

I would like to format the dialogue text while using the **dialogue** package.
I have already made the speaker bold, but was not able to **format the text of speakers**. I would like to have the text to be kind of in a box (without indentation)

When using the following script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dialogue}
% bold the speaker name
\renewcommand*\DialogueLabel[1]{%
  \scshape\textbf{#1}:\hfil
}

\begin{document}

\begin{dialogue}
    \speak{Marie} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    \speak{Marine} What?
\end{dialogue}
```

I get the following result, where the second line of a paragraph is not aligned with the first line:

[image: Current Result]

**What I desire is the following format** (the italic font and quotations are optional):

[image]

Many Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Danke dir. Habe ich hier etw falsch gemacht? Kriege keine Antwort.

Comment: If one name is longer than the other, do you want the paragraph blocks to start in different places, e..g, should Marine's dialogues start further right than Marie's because the name is longer? Or do you want all names to start in the same place?

Comment: Good point. I guess I could make the speaker names smaller (either less letters or smaller font) so all the paragraph blocks start in the same place for all speakers. This way both the place of speaker names and paragraph blocks would be static.

Comment: @frabjous just in case you haven't received notification.

Comment: @Jerry Manchmal muss man etwas Geduld haben ...

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the effect you want, I think what you'd need to do is redefine the dialogue environment so that the `\labelwidth` is set to the width of the longest character name, and set the `\leftmargin` to exactly that plus the value of `\labelsep` (the width of the space between the name label and text), which I've set to `0.5em`.

You can use the `calc` package's `\widthof{...}` command to determine the length of the longest character name. Below, I assume it is "Marina", but if you have character with longer names, you'll need to change the `\setlength{\widestname}{...` command appropriately.

For example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % necessary for bold small caps
\usepackage{setspace} % for double spacing
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage{calc} % to measure width of widest name
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\renewcommand*\DialogueLabel[1]{%
  \scshape\textbf{#1}:\hfil
}

% set width of widest name
\newlength{\widestname}
\setlength{\widestname}{%
    \widthof{\textbf{\textsc{Marina}}:}
}

% redefine dialogue environment to use new parameters
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{dialogue} {%
    \begin{list}{} {%
        \setlength\itemsep{\z@ \@plus .5ex}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}% no indentation on right; change this if you wish
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{\widestname}% set label to widest width
        \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}% space between (longest) name and text
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}% set margin on left to same width
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}% plus the label sep
        \defcommand\speak [1] {\item[{##1}]}% define speak command
        \let\makelabel\DialogueLabel
      }%
      \PreDialogue\relax
    }{%
  \end{list}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\doublespacing

\lipsum[1][3-9]

\begin{dialogue}

\speak{Maria} \lipsum[2][1-2]

\speak{Marina} \lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{dialogue}

\end{document}
```

This gives this output.

[image: dialogue with paragraphs after names]

If you also want the italics and quotation marks around each dialogue, I think you'd need to use slightly different syntax. You could change the definition of `\speak` to take two arguments, and put the second argument in italics and quotes. That is, change the line of the `\renewenvironment` for `dialogue` above which reads:

```latex
\defcommand\speak [1] {\item[{##1}]}%
```

Into this:

```latex
\defcommand\speak[2]{\item[{##1}] {\itshape ``{##2}''}}%
```

And then you'd have to write the dialogue like so, with braces around both the names and the actual dialogue text:

```latex
\speak{Maria}{Nam dui ligula, fingilla \ldots}

\speak{Marina}{Lorem ipsum dolor \dots}
```

And you'd get this.

[image: with italics and quotes]

Stylistically I might also consider right-aligning the names against the text:

```latex
\defcommand\speak[2]{\item[\hfill {##1}] {\itshape ``{##2}''}}%
```

[image: With right-aligned names]

The dialogue package isn't that complex. You've basically rewritten half of it at this point; you might consider just doing without it and using `\enuitem` or similar package to set up the dialogue, but that's a separate topic.

(Looks like I changed "Marie" into "Maria"; oh well, I don't suppose it matters for demonstrating the solution.)